# jQuery load event for element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we can select `item` using Jquery like this:

```
 var item = $('[aria-label="rect"] svg');
```

The thing I don't know is, why I'm not able to detect if the `item` has been loaded using this:

```
 setInterval(function(){ 

      item.load(function() {
      console.log('item has been loaded!');
      });
      // or this one:
      item.on("load", function() {
      console.log('item has been loaded!');
      })

  }, 100);
```

Note: I can animate the item at the same time, I'm sure that my selector works fine:

```
var item = $('[aria-label="rect"] svg');
item.animate({'top': '-=50px'},'slow');  // Animation works fine

  setInterval(function(){ 

      item.load(function() {
      // Handler for .load() called.
      console.log('item has been loaded!');
      });

      item.on("load", function() {
      console.log('item has been loaded!');
      })

  }, 100);
```

**The original problem:**

I'm using Articulate Storyline to create a simple page. On the page, there is a rectangle that animates from right to left, right after the user enters the page. I noticed that in slow connections the rectangle animation doesn't play or plays from the middle of the animation at the first run of the page. after the page is cached the users never encounter this issue, only the first time. now I think one solution is to initiate the animation only if we are sure that the rectangle has been loaded.

Comment: The issue is because for the jQuery to run and successfully select the element it must already have been loaded in to the DOM. Therefore your goal is redundant.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan I can animate the item at the same time, I'm sure that my selector works fine...

Comment: That's my point, for the selector to work the load event has already fired.

Comment: I don't understand... if the load event has already fired shouldn't we see the console logs???

Comment: How can I fix this... ???

Comment: `if the load event has already fired shouldn't we see the console logs` no, as `svg` elements don't fire a load event (the `document` and `img` elements do - this is what I meant in my previous comment, apologies if I caused confsion). How you fix this depends on exactly what you're trying to do, and why.

Comment: Is there a solution to check if an element has been loaded already  using jquery?

Comment: To reword @RoryMcCrossan first comment.  1) `$("item").length != 0` means the item has already loaded.  2) `.load()` on an already loaded element won't fire as it's already loaded: `$(document).load(function() { console.log("test"); })` does nothing.  1)+2) confirming your selector works confirms that it has already loaded.  **extra** svc doesn't raise `load` event *anyway* so would never fire.

Comment: No. As I mentioned in my first comment, for jQuery to run the element must already have been loaded in to the DOM. This is why I'm asking you to explain why you feel that you need to do whatever it is you're trying to do

Comment: We get the impression that what you are calling "*detect if the item has been loaded*" - is different what we call "loaded".  So you'll need to explain in more detail.

Comment: Ok ... I'll edit the question to explain why I need this...

Comment: Can you add your html and show us whether you embed an SVG source or the svg code directly? In latter case no load event will be fired cause the SVG does not need to get loaded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan For the object to be in the DOM and selectable its html needs to be rendered, it does not need to be fully loaded if it handles a source.

Comment: @foxer the setinterval makes no sense. Just add the event listener. You can console.log the length of your selection before adding the listener to see if the element is already there.

Comment: `$("item").length != 0` returns false? what that mean...

Comment: and sorry for the delay... we had an earthquake a moment ago here... :)

Comment: @foxer item already is your collection, `console.log(item.length)` should give you an answer how many items your selector found. Since the animation works, I do expect something >0 Anyway, to see if your svg can/does sends an load event at all, you can try adding the onload attribute to your tag.

Comment: I'm testing `item.length` on the server...

Comment: Please correct me If I'm wrong: If `item.length == 1` then we can say that the item is ready and loaded to animate and render...???!

Comment: @foxer The html element is ready. If your svg is has a src attribute it still might need to load. But if it has no src attribute (but is direct svg code) then it is all ready for action.

Comment: Ok thanks ... time to test again..